# Using resultset data after closing the connection

Tags: java, sql, jdbc

I'm trying to write a small code snippet where I need to get some data from a database and then process the result in some other java file. I tried writing a program and the execution for the same was failing with error "Cannot access resultset as the connection was already closed".

Is there any way can we store the result fetched from database some where (Ex.some arraylist) and use it for computation after closing the connection? If yes, can someone please explain it with example?
Slightly handicapped since I'm new to it.

```
Class A { 

  public Map<String, Object> loadDat(int acc,Map<String,Object> result) 
      throws Exception { 
    Class.forName("com.teradata.jdbc.TeraDriver"); 
    Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionString, user, password); 
    query = "select * from mytable where id="+acc; 
    PreparedStatement stmt = conn.prepareStatement(query); 
    ResultSet rs=stmt.executeQuery(); 
    result.put(" Result", rs) ; 
    return result; 
  }

}
```

Comment: There is such a way… Could you please add your code that fetches the data?

Comment: Hi @deHaar,     ``` Class A{
    public Map<String, Object> loadDat(int acc,Map<String,Object> result) throws Exception
     {
           Class.forName("com.teradata.jdbc.TeraDriver");
            Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionString, user, password);
             query = "select * from mytable where id="+acc;
             PreparedStatement stmt=conn.prepareStatement(query);
             ResultSet rs=stmt.executeQuery();
             result.put(" Result", rs) ;
             return result;
   }}``` can you kindly explain how do I achieve it?

Comment: Are you really trying to put the `ResultSet` into itself? Use something else, a `Map<String, String>` or some `List<YourCustomObject>`. You can declare it as class attribute, initialize it (e.g. in the constructor) and then either directly add `String`s or primitive typed values to the data structure or create a custom object from the data of the `ResultSet` and store that one in a `List` or similar. Oh, you want to return a `Map<String, Object>`, what kind of `Object` do you want to return? Just `Object` is not that good, I think...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general,
don't code JDBC database access by hand.
Libraries already exist that do all the low level JDBC handling now and
they do it correctly.
You will never do it better than an one of the mature,
open source projects already do it.

Instead,
learn and use something like [MyBatis](http://www.mybatis.org/mybatis-3).
If you use Spring,
here is a link to the [Mybatis-Spring project](http://www.mybatis.org/spring/index.html).

MyBatis conceals all of the data conversion and JDBC junk.
Instead, you define your query in a simple XML file and receive a List
as the result of a query.

Answer (score 0):

Just to add to @DwB's answer that is correct.

You can 1) retrieve all rows from your query into a Java List, 2) then close the connection, and 3) then use the Java List in another class (for further processing).

If you close the connection after retrieving only part of the result set, you'll lose the rest of it and will receive the error you mention. Don't do it this way.